# How do I fix my slider? It isn't working as intended

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a slider that will set the bins in matplotlib, here is my code:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import ion
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.widgets import RadioButtons
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider


# generate 4 random variables from the random, gamma, exponential, and uniform distributions
sample_size = 10000
normal = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=sample_size)
gamma = np.random.gamma(shape = 1.0, scale=1.0, size=sample_size)
uniform = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=10.0, size=sample_size)
exponential = np.random.exponential(scale=1.0, size=sample_size)

fig, sub_plt = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.65) # Adjust subplot to not overlap with radio box

axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
rax = plt.axes([0.05, 0.7, 0.25, 0.25], facecolor=axcolor)
axfreq = plt.axes([0.20, 0.02, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)
radio = RadioButtons(rax, ('Normal', 'Gamma', 'Uniform', 'Exponential'))
slide = Slider(axfreq, 'Bins', 10.0,200.0,valinit=30.0)

def dist_func(type_l):
    sub_plt.clear() # comment this line if you want to keep previous drawings
    dist_dict = {'Normal':normal, 'Gamma':gamma, 'Uniform':uniform, 'Exponential':exponential}
    data_type = dist_dict[type_l]
    sub_plt.hist(data_type, bins=100)


radio.on_clicked(dist_func)

def bin_func(val):
    slide_val = slide.val
    plt.figure()
    sub_plt.hist(data_type,bins=slide_val)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()


 slide.on_changed(bin_func)

 plt.show()
```

I want the value of the slider to set the bins of the histogram. This renders the slider but the slider does not set the bins as intended, in fact it doesn't do anything. Is there any way to make the bins work as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `sub_plt.hist(data_type,bins=slide_val)` is the problem, data_type isn't a global variable so you can't create a plot with an undefined variable.

I moved the canvas redrawing code to inside the `dist_func` so that clicking one of the radio buttons redraws the plot without having to move the slider.

It is also important to ensure the slider value is an integer (must have a discrete number of bins!)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets import RadioButtons
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

# generate 4 random variables from the random, gamma, exponential, and uniform distributions
sample_size = 10000
normal = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=sample_size)
gamma = np.random.gamma(shape=1.0, scale=1.0, size=sample_size)
uniform = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=10.0, size=sample_size)
exponential = np.random.exponential(scale=1.0, size=sample_size)

fig, sub_plt = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.65)  # Adjust subplot to not overlap with radio box

axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
rax = plt.axes([0.05, 0.7, 0.25, 0.25], facecolor=axcolor)
axfreq = plt.axes([0.20, 0.02, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)
radio = RadioButtons(rax, ('Normal', 'Gamma', 'Uniform', 'Exponential'))
slide = Slider(axfreq, 'Bins', 10.0, 200.0, valinit=30.0, valstep=1)

dist_dict = {'Normal': normal, 'Gamma': gamma, 'Uniform': uniform, 'Exponential': exponential}


def dist_func(type_l, bins=100):
    sub_plt.clear()  # comment this line if you want to keep previous drawings
    data_type = dist_dict[type_l]
    sub_plt.hist(data_type, bins=bins)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()


radio.on_clicked(dist_func)


def update(a):
    dist_func(radio.value_selected, bins=int(a))



# the final step is to specify that the slider needs to
# execute the above function when its value changes
slide.on_changed(update)
dist_func('Normal', bins=100)
plt.show()
```